# Background image won't apply

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a background image but in a div that will make it blurry. The website is being made for a friend, and i'm having issues with this. I have put all of the html and css into a codepen. The codepen link is [here.](http://codepen.io/evantheis/pen/QbqpWX)

```
div.background{
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/DDqQLdi.png);
opacity: 0.6;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);}
```

This does not apply the background, it applies it only on the words the way it currently seems.

In case i'm not being very clear on my wants, I want to put this image inside of a div which will make the background image blurry, and then I plan on putting another image and a line on front of the image.

Thanks to anybody that will offer any kind of help, all is appreciated, as well as any tips of achieving my goal!

Does the image need to be into the body instead of the background class?

Comment: The background image _does_ get applied – but you don’t see much of it, because that div element is only as high as the text content demands.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was looking into your code.

This is what's wrong, your css should only contain this

```
body {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/DDqQLdi.png");
opacity: 0.6;
filter:alpha(opacity=60); }
```

Comment: Doing that made my h2 heading use the same thing. I'm trying to only make the background have the opacity.

Comment: _“I'm trying to only make the background have the opacity”_ – that is not possible, `opacity` affects an element and _all_ its content. In that case, you would need to use a dedicated element just for the background image, and position it behind the rest of the content in some way. Or use a PNG image with an alpha transparency of 60% set on all pixels to begin with.

Comment: I do not have photoshop or any kind of photo editing software on this website, but I do already have an element in place. Look at the html and I have a background div. Would I not want to use a div?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give that div some height because at the moment it only shows up as the background for the content within it, just the h2 tag.

Alternatively you can apply the image to the body, which is probably a better solution